# Replace certain records in a column of a table with another table by matching other columns

Tags: r, merge, left-join

I want to replace some records in t1$x3 with another table t2 (note that all other columns are same except x3):

```
t1 <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,7,3,4,2,6),
                 x2 = c("I","R","R","I","I","R"),
                 x3 = c("a","a","a","a","a","a"))
t2 <- data.frame(x1 = c(4,2,6),
                 x2 = c("I","I","R"),
                 x3 = c("b","b","b"))
t1
#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  1  I  a
# 2  7  R  a
# 3  3  R  a
# 4  4  I  a
# 5  2  I  a
# 6  6  R  a

t2
#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  4  I  b
# 2  2  I  b
# 3  6  R  b
```

The result is supposed to be like this：

```
data.frame(x1 = c(1,7,3,4,2,6),
           x2 = c("I","R","R","I","I","R"),
           x3 = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"))

#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  1  I  a
# 2  7  R  a
# 3  3  R  a
# 4  4  I  b
# 5  2  I  b
# 6  6  R  b
```

How can I do it?

Comment: what would be the rule for replacement?, if `x1` and `x2` from `t2` have a match in `t1`, then replace the value in `t1$x3` with the corresponding value from `t2$x3`?

Comment: @Vincent Bonhomme. Consider that I have to match both x1 and x2 to replace the values needed to be replaced in t1$x3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Left join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join) then update:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(t1, t2, by = c("x1", "x2"), all.x = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(x3 = ifelse(is.na(x3.y), as.character(x3.x), as.character(x3.y))) %>% 
  select(-c(x3.x, x3.y))

#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  1  I  a
# 2  7  R  a
# 3  3  R  a
# 4  4  I  b
# 5  2  I  b
# 6  6  R  b
```

Using base R:

```
# left join 
res <- merge(t1, t2, by = c("x1", "x2"), all.x = TRUE)
# update x3
res$x3 <- ifelse(is.na(res$x3.y), as.character(res$x3.x), as.character(res$x3.y))
# subset and reorder
res <- res[match(t1$x1, res$x1), c("x1", "x2", "x3")]
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I do it with "match" or "merge"? Because I have problem with loading dplyr.

Comment: @JadaChang added base solution.

Answer (score 2):

We can try with `data.table`.  It should be very fast as we are assigning (`:=`) in place.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(t1)`), join with 't2' `on` 'x1' and 'x2', then assign 'i.x3' values to 'x3'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(t1)[t2, x3 := i.x3, on = c("x1", "x2")]
t1
#   x1 x2 x3
#1:  1  I  a
#2:  7  R  a
#3:  3  R  a
#4:  4  I  b
#5:  2  I  b
#6:  6  R  b
```

---

Or we can use `match`

```
t1$x3 <- factor(t1$x3, levels = c('a','b'))
t1[match(do.call(paste,t2[-3]), do.call(paste, t1[-3])), 'x3'] <- t2$x3
t1
# x1 x2 x3
#1  1  I  a
#2  7  R  a
#3  3  R  a
#4  4  I  b
#5  2  I  b
#6  6  R  b
```

Comment: Still trying to digest your match solution... :)

Comment: @zx8754 I `paste`d the first columns of each dataset and did the `match`.  Is that too bad :-)

Comment: Error report: There is no 'setDT' function..   What if there are many levels of x3, not only 'a' and 'b',how to use the 'match' function?

Comment: @JadaChang  Have you loaded the `library(data.table)`?  Also, if loaded, which version do you have?  I am using `>=1.9.6`

Comment: @JadaChang  I tried both in `1.9.6` and `1.9.7` and it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would give what you want.

Convert `x3` column to character in `t1` and `t2`and then check the condition

```
t1$x3 <- as.character(t1$x3)
t2$x3 <- as.character(t2$x3)
t1[t1$x1 %in% t2$x1 & as.character(t1$x2) %in% as.character(t2$x2), "x3"] <- t2$x3

> t1
#  x1 x2 x3
#1  1  I  a
#2  7  R  a
#3  3  R  a
#4  4  I  b
#5  2  I  b
#6  6  R  b
```

Comment: In addition to the assumtpions mentioned here, it also assumes that 't1' and 't2' columns are in the same order along with it dependency on the recycling (which may not work in most of the cases)

Comment: It didn't work, I got this:  x1 x2   x3
1  1  I    a
2  7  R    a
3  3  R    a
4  4  I <NA>
5  2  I <NA>
6  6  R <NA>

Comment: This works only for the example posted.  I don't think it will work for any other cases.

Comment: I can use `%in%` but I thought the order has to be maintained.

Comment: t1<-data.frame(x1=c(1,7,3,4,2,6),x2=c("I","R","R","I","I","R"),x3=c("a","a","a","a","a","a"))
t2<-data.frame(x1=c(4,2,6),x2=c("I","I","R"),x3=c("b","b","b"))t1[t1$x1 == t2$x1 & t1$x2 == t2$x2, "x3"] <- t2$x3
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: The reason is that you have factor column, which needs to be converted to either character class or create another level as I showed in my post